# SVG Image in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use svg image in react-native. I am using WebView to display the mage. But it is showing some fluctuation while scrolling.
Here is my sample code :

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {AppRegistry,Alert,WebView,View,ScrollView} = React;

var Sample = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var data = [
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"},
            {uri: "http://www.kameleon.pics/img/pill-svg.svg"}
        ];
        var dataToShow = data.map((record, index)=> {
            return (
                <WebView key={`ic_`+index} source={{uri:record.uri}} style={{height:80,width:80}}></WebView>
            )
        });
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {dataToShow}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => Sample);
```

Is there any other way better than WebView to use svg image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34734113/1206613

Comment: @Cherniv I have already gone through this link. It is working with WebView but showing fluctuation while scrolling. Is using svg image is a bad thing in react-native?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create icons from SVG. You can create icons from [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io). After that use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) in your projects. You have to follow installation steps correctly. After that you can use your custom font icons in your app.