# React Native display SVG from a file

Tags: svg, react-native

How do I display an SVG image that I `require()` in React Native.

- https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svgkit Is not under active development.
- https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg Can't figure out how to load a file.
- WebView (or Bridged WebView) Can't figure out how to load a required file.

What's the best way to just display the image (don't need to manipulate it).

Or should I just be converting it to a png instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG use in React Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716281/svg-use-in-react-native-project)

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a png is the easiest solution. SVG Images are listed in [ProductPains](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/support-rendering-svg-images) as a pain point and you may upvote it, if you see the need, but for now there is no great out of the box solution for svg images.

Answer (score 3):

You can hack around this using a webview. I also had to put my SVGs as strings in .js files (which is not good at all). But it works pretty reliably. There is a split second where they show up as white before the SVG loads, but it's good enough for me.

Roughly something like:

```
import React, { View, WebView } from 'react-native'
import s from 'string'

const firstHtml = '<html><head><style>html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden } svg { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100% }</style></head><body>'
const lastHtml = '</body></html>'
export default (props) =>
  <View style={props.containerStyle}>
    <WebView
      style={[{ width: 200, height: 100, backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }, normalizeStyle(props.style)]}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      source={{ html: `${firstHtml}${props.svgContent}${lastHtml}` }}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've published an npm package for this at `react-native-remote-svg`

Answer (score 2):

You can display small SVG file as data using this library,

**Note**: Large SVG images are not rendering properly.

> npm i react-native-remote-svg

```
import Image from 'react-native-remote-svg'

<Image
 source={{
uri: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="100px" height="100px"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <ellipse data-custom-shape="ellipse" cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50" 
fill="green"  stroke="#00FF00" stroke-width ="2" />
   </svg>`
}}
style={{ width: 100, height: 100}}
/>
```

If you want to display any size of images remotely with above library and then do this,

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/my-pic.svg' }}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 532}}
/>
```

But if you used this one for display the local svg file, then you will get some issues in android when you bundle and put the release.

```
import Image from 'react-native-remote-svg'
<Image source={require('./image.svg')} />
```

or you can use Icomoon (For small SVG images/Icons),

**Recommended**: Use Icomoon for Icons and Small SVG Images

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u86IQHgDg8Y) to setup the icomoon in react native

Comment: Don't use this plugin `react-native-remote-svg` since it has serious bug in Android in Production mode. iOS is fine though.

Comment: @somnathbm yeah. But this bug is only for local svg images. If you use for remote SVGs then it works fine.