# How to show SVG file on React Native?

Tags: javascript, svg, react-native

I want to show svg files (I have bunch of svg images) but the thing I couldn't find the way to show. I tried to use **Image** and **Use** components of **[react-native-svg](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg)** but they don't work with that. And I tried to do that with native way but it's really hard work to show just svg image.

Example code:

```
import Svg, {
  Use,
  Image,
} from 'react-native-svg';

<View>
  <Svg width="80" height="80">
     <Image href={require('./svg/1f604.svg')} />
  </SvgRn>
</View>
```

Also I know the react native doesn't support svg basically but I think someone fixed this problem with tricky way (with/without react-native-svg)

Comment: You can't use use to display an entire file, you'd need image for that.

Comment: Yeah i tried it too @RobertLongson but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You can add it as css backgroundImage, did you tried it?

Comment: I tried but react native View component doesn't support backgroundImage prop on css style. @danielarend

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use an SVG wrapper to wrap an SVG image.

Comment: @RobertLongson because Image component of RN doesn't support SVG file. When i try to use "react-native-svg" component, i need to put the code inside of SVG wrapper.

Comment: You could just display the SVG file via a html img surely.

Answer (score 154):

I used the following solution:

1. Convert `.svg` image to JSX with https://svg2jsx.herokuapp.com/
2. Convert the JSX to `react-native-svg` component with https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true (make sure the "React Native" checkbox is checked)

Comment: How to use that Component then? Can you share a code?

Comment: If you follow this link you'll see an example with imports https://svgr.now.sh/ (check the "React Native checkbox). Use it as a regular React component, place it instead of <Image src={...}/> and it should work.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko when I tired your solution, i got this error **Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object**. could you help me here?

Comment: @Kishore make sure you are importing/exporting/using your component correctly. Try to search SO for the error message you got and you'll find plenty of different cases.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko I tried to render simple **<Text>** component. It worked fine. But when i tried to render Svg(converted Jsx), I got the error. Could let me know how to render the converted jsx code in react component

Comment: @Kishore did you do the second step "Convert JSX to React Component"? You need to check the "React Native" checkbox if you want React Native code. Hard to say what is wrong but those two steps I posted above worked for me.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko It's working fine now. I didn't import 'G' from package.

Comment: Hi @IhorBurlachenko. Step 1 to step 2 doesn't work. But only step 2 works and when I put the component on my code, my app close. Any help?

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong because I'm not maintaining those sites. Re your app I'm pretty sure you can find something useful in the logs.

Comment: Anybody who has issue using this approach, please make sure that you do install the latest version of `react-native-svg` package. Also make sure to run this command to link your package `react-native link react-native-svg`

Comment: This is a long process to implement SVG files, better use https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer as suggested below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604442/1854104

Comment: Works fine for me but I'm losing the shadow details :( any sugestions to this?

Comment: This is such a nightmare to do when you have hundreds of icons from your design.

Comment: Does this support animated SVG? Cause I tried it, it works, but it didn't animate.

Comment: It's animating now, I was testing in NextJS (react-native-web), and the JSX must be formatted for normal React instead of React Native. So you have to get 2 versions of each if you're using Web too.

Comment: i cant believe over 140 people upvoted this as a good answer

Comment: link 2 is great.

Comment: link 1 is broken.

Comment: @IsmailS use that one: https://svg2jsx.com/

Answer (score 27):

Install [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer)

> npm i react-native-svg-transformer --save-dev

I'm using SVG as following and it works fine

```
import LOGOSVG from "assets/svg/logo.svg"
```

in render

```
<View>
  <LOGOSVG 
    width="100%"
    height="70%"
  />
</View>
```

Comment: When i am importing svg file HEARTSVG from image folder then it showing error. And no error to import png files. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 26):

I posted **another solution (react-native-vector-icons)** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951885/how-can-i-insert-an-image-in-svg-format-into-a-reactnative-application/49952050#49952050). This approach use a vector font (from SVG) instead a SVG file.
PS: react-native-vector-icons is the best approach to deal with SVG in react-native, it's also works in iOS and android. You will be able to change the color and size of your vector icon.

If you want to insert a svg directly into your app, you can try a 3rd party library : react-native-svg. With more than 3k stars in github it's one of the best approach.

Install any one of these using `npm`:

- [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)
- [react-native-svg-uri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-uri)

Then link it to native using

```sh
react-native link react-native-svg
```

An example with [`react-native-svg-uri`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-uri):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri'; // SVG Package
import testSvg from './test.svg';          // SVG File

export default () => (
  <SvgUri
    width="200"
    height="200"
    svgXmlData={testSvg}
  />
);
```

Comment: It gives an error "cannot add a child that doesn t have a css node to a node without a measure function".

Comment: I used last one with source={require('myImagePath')} but it gives me error.

Comment: Look the answer I post here, using a font instead a svg. it's a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951885/how-can-i-insert-an-image-in-svg-format-into-a-reactnative-application/49952050#49952050

Comment: This library is so slow. It wraps every svg in its own webview.

Comment: @JP_ I have updated the answer, for svg in react-native we have basically 2 approachs: 1: convert the icons with  fontello.com and embed it in the app with react-native-vector-icons or 2: use react-native-svg-uri.

Comment: tnx, this was quickest solution, but instead of svgXmlData={testSvg} i used source={testSvg} worked like a charm. tnx again.

Comment: That good @AndrisLaduzans, Plus I will suggest you to take a look in the best approach in the link at my answer. It's really good for performance aspects. I will recompense your efforts.

Comment: ERROR SVG, [TypeError: this.state.svgXmlData.indexOf is not a function. (In 'this.state.svgXmlData.indexOf("<svg ")', 'this.state.svgXmlData.indexOf' is undefined)]

Comment: @Omarbakhsh I would recommend you to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951885/which-is-the-best-approach-to-insert-an-vector-svg-graph-into-a-react-native-a/49952050#49952050

Answer (score 18):

I've tried all the above solutions and other solutions outside of the stack and none of working for me. finally, after long research, I've found one solution for my expo project.

If you need it to work in expo, one workaround might be to use https://react-svgr.com/playground/ and move the spreading of props to a G element instead of the SVG root like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Svg, { G, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Svg viewBox="0 0 511 511">
      <G {...props}>
        <Path d="M131.5 96c-11.537 0-21.955 8.129-29.336 22.891C95.61 132 92 149.263 92 167.5s3.61 35.5 10.164 48.609C109.545 230.871 119.964 239 131.5 239s21.955-8.129 29.336-22.891C167.39 203 171 185.737 171 167.5s-3.61-35.5-10.164-48.609C153.455 104.129 143.037 96 131.5 96zm15.92 113.401C142.78 218.679 136.978 224 131.5 224s-11.28-5.321-15.919-14.599C110.048 198.334 107 183.453 107 167.5s3.047-30.834 8.581-41.901C120.22 116.321 126.022 111 131.5 111s11.28 5.321 15.919 14.599C152.953 136.666 156 151.547 156 167.5s-3.047 30.834-8.58 41.901z" />
        <Path d="M474.852 158.011c-1.263-40.427-10.58-78.216-26.555-107.262C430.298 18.023 405.865 0 379.5 0h-248c-26.365 0-50.798 18.023-68.797 50.749C45.484 82.057 36 123.52 36 167.5s9.483 85.443 26.703 116.751C80.702 316.977 105.135 335 131.5 335a57.57 57.57 0 005.867-.312 7.51 7.51 0 002.133.312h48a7.5 7.5 0 000-15h-16c10.686-8.524 20.436-20.547 28.797-35.749 4.423-8.041 8.331-16.756 11.703-26.007V503.5a7.501 7.501 0 0011.569 6.3l20.704-13.373 20.716 13.374a7.498 7.498 0 008.134 0l20.729-13.376 20.729 13.376a7.49 7.49 0 004.066 1.198c1.416 0 2.832-.4 4.07-1.2l20.699-13.372 20.726 13.374a7.5 7.5 0 008.133 0l20.732-13.377 20.738 13.377a7.5 7.5 0 008.126.003l20.783-13.385 20.783 13.385a7.5 7.5 0 0011.561-6.305v-344a7.377 7.377 0 00-.146-1.488zM187.154 277.023C171.911 304.737 152.146 320 131.5 320s-40.411-15.263-55.654-42.977C59.824 247.891 51 208.995 51 167.5s8.824-80.391 24.846-109.523C91.09 30.263 110.854 15 131.5 15s40.411 15.263 55.654 42.977C203.176 87.109 212 126.005 212 167.5s-8.824 80.391-24.846 109.523zm259.563 204.171a7.5 7.5 0 00-8.122 0l-20.78 13.383-20.742-13.38a7.5 7.5 0 00-8.131 0l-20.732 13.376-20.729-13.376a7.497 7.497 0 00-8.136.002l-20.699 13.373-20.727-13.375a7.498 7.498 0 00-8.133 0l-20.728 13.375-20.718-13.375a7.499 7.499 0 00-8.137.001L227 489.728V271h8.5a7.5 7.5 0 000-15H227v-96.5c0-.521-.054-1.03-.155-1.521-1.267-40.416-10.577-78.192-26.548-107.231C191.936 35.547 182.186 23.524 171.5 15h208c20.646 0 40.411 15.263 55.654 42.977C451.176 87.109 460 126.005 460 167.5V256h-.5a7.5 7.5 0 000 15h.5v218.749l-13.283-8.555z" />
        <Path d="M283.5 256h-16a7.5 7.5 0 000 15h16a7.5 7.5 0 000-15zM331.5 256h-16a7.5 7.5 0 000 15h16a7.5 7.5 0 000-15zM379.5 256h-16a7.5 7.5 0 000 15h16a7.5 7.5 0 000-15zM427.5 256h-16a7.5 7.5 0 000 15h16a7.5 7.5 0 000-15z" />
      </G>
    </Svg>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SvgComponent width="100%" height="100%" strokeWidth={5} stroke="black" />
  );
}
```

Comment: This is also working fine for me. We can easily get the path of svg file by opening it on browser & view page source and then directly use the path & replace <path /> tag with react-native-svg <Path />. 

BIG THANKS

Comment: I had to set `width` & `height` to the wrapping `View`, otherwise the **easiest and most straightforward** way since **you basically use your regular `<svg>`** and just replace tags with the ones from `react-native-svg` as @Rakesh said right!

Answer (score 16):

Method that is working for me in 2022 for anyone that is still stuck on this, **react native version** 0.63.4, **react-native-svg** version ^12.1.0, you may be able to use this method for other versions too but always check the docs for the library first:

1. Install `react-native-svg-transformer` by running this command `yarn add react-native-svg-transformer --dev` or using npm if you prefer `npm i react-native-svg react-native-svg-transformer --save-dev`
2. Install `babel-plugin-inline-import` by running `yarn add babel-plugin-inline-import --dev`
3. You need to update your `metro.config.js` file to looks like this:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false
        }
      })
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg']
    }
  };
})();
```

4. Make sure to import your svg file into your component like this: `import CreditCard from '../assets/CreditCard';` please note how I am not adding the `.svg` file extension to the import, this is because it was giving me this error `view config getter callback react-native-svg` while running it but removing it seems to make it run smoothly. You can add your file this way as a jsx element like that `<CreditCard />`.
5. Finally Restart your packager by stopping it using `^Ctrl + C` on mac then restart it again with this command `yarn start:dev --reset-cache` and install the app again.

Answer (score 12):

After trying many ways and libraries I decided to create a new font (with [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/) or this [tutorial](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application)) and add my SVG files to it, then use "Text" component with my custom font.

Hope this helps anyone that has the same problem with SVG in react-native.

Comment: I think you are right, a font family is probably the easiest way to get simple svgs into react native

Comment: Nice tutorial on that subject: https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application. Requires the [Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) Node package.

Comment: This solution isn't valid if you need to import multi-color sag file

Comment: I have tried its solution with icomoon and it didn't work out neither their support are active. And fontello is altering my svgs.

Answer (score 12):

you can do this using a simple way

## first, you should take installation,

1. npm install -s react-native-svg
2. react-native link react-native-svg
3. npm install -s react-native-svg-transformer

## then, you should add the following code in your metro.config.js file

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

## after that, you should create a new file in your root directory with the name of declarations.d.js with the following code

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
  import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";
  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}
```

Finally,
This is a import mathod

```html
import USER from "../../assets/icons/user.svg"
```

and, this is for jsx

```html
<USER width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

SVG does not support directly in Native applications. For displaying those we need to take help of third party modules

Please follow these steps

**step 1**. Install ***react-native-svg*** and ***react-native-svg-transformer***

```
npm i react-native-svg react-native-svg-transformer
```

**step 2**. Add file **metro.config.js** if it doesn't exist

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => { 
    const {  
        resolver: { 
            sourceExts, 
            assetExts 
        }  
    } = await getDefaultConfig(); 

    return {
        transformer: {      
            babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")    
        },    
        resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]    
        }};
})();
```

**step 3**. Use SVG file like a React component

```
import Invest from '../assets/invest.svg'; // import SVG

return (
        <View>
            <Invest /> // Use SVG as component
        </View>
    )
```

Comment: Great what you share but i realize that **react-native-svg-transformer** have to be install as dev dependencies so like you install :
First: `yarn add react-native-svg` or `npm i --save react-native-svg`
and then: `yarn add react-native-svg-transformer -D` or `npm i --dev react-native-svg-transformer`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I'm using this solution I found: [React Native display SVG from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098243/react-native-display-svg-from-a-file)

It's not perfect, and i'm revisiting today, because it performs a lot worse on Android.

Comment: Actually it's creative answer but it doesn't help my fits :) Because i will use icon list (10 or more SVG icons) so if i use this, it can be really bad for performance i guess. What do you think?

Comment: I rendered 10-15 svgs on a page. Nobody complained on iOS, everyone complained on Android.

On iOS there is a 0.1-0.3 second delay (a split second flash of white before it loads). On Android it can be 1 second, and sometimes they never load.

In the end I checked in my SVGs, then wrote a script which converts them to PNGs of exactly the correct size using [svg2png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2png). Then used `<Image>` with those PNGs. Given the current state of SVG in react native, there is no ETA for SVGs working, so this is your best bet if you can't tolerate the work around.

Answer (score 4):

Use https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer

In this package it is mentioned that `.svg` files are not supported in React Native v0.57 and lower so use `.svgx` extension for svg files.

For web or react-native-web use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack

---

To render svg files using `react-native-svg-uri` with react-native version 0.57 and lower, you need to add following files to your root project

> Note: change extension `svg` to `svgx`

### step 1: add file `transformer.js` to project's root

```js
// file: transformer.js

const cleanupSvg = require('./cleanup-svg');

const upstreamTransformer = require("metro/src/transformer");

// const typescriptTransformer = require("react-native-typescript-transformer");
// const typescriptExtensions = ["ts", "tsx"];

const svgExtensions = ["svgx"]

// function cleanUpSvg(text) {
//   text = text.replace(/width="([#0-9]+)px"/gi, "");
//    text = text.replace(/height="([#0-9]+)px"/gi, "");
//    return text;
// }

function fixRenderingBugs(content) {
  // content = cleanUpSvg(content); // cleanupSvg removes width and height attributes from svg
  return "module.exports = `" + content + "`";
}


module.exports.transform = function ({ src, filename, options }) {
  // if (typescriptExtensions.some(ext => filename.endsWith("." + ext))) {
  //  return typescriptTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options })
  // }

  if (svgExtensions.some(ext => filename.endsWith("." + ext))) {
    return upstreamTransformer.transform({
      src: fixRenderingBugs(src),
      filename,
      options
    })
  }

  return upstreamTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
}
```

### step 2: add `rn-cli.config.js` to project's root

```
module.exports = {
    getTransformModulePath() {
      return require.resolve("./transformer");
    },
    getSourceExts() {
      return [/* "ts", "tsx", */ "svgx"];
    }
  };
```

The above mentioned solutions will work in production apps too ✅

Answer (score 3):

you can convert any SVG to a component and make it reusable.

here is my answer for the easiest way you can do it

[SVG to component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64124975/12861001)

Answer (score 3):

Using svg in a react native project is not as simple as using it in the web, although it is not that difficult either.

> **Many of the above answers are complicated in my view. So, here is the solution that I use and like.**

Since react native does not support the svg file format directly you need to  follow some steps to get it working.

***1. Install  react-native-svg***

```
 npm install react-native-svg --save
```

This package will help you render the svg file

***2. Install  react-native-svg-transformer***

```
npm install react-native-svg-transformer --save
```

This package will transform your svg to the format that react native understands.

***3. Import the svg as normal component***

```
import Belsvg from "../assets/belsvg.svg";
```

While importing give it a name that you like now this svg is transformed into a react native component by the  `react-native-svg-transformer`

***4. Now you can use this as a normal component***

For a detailed explanation and example visit the link :

https://kumar2396jayant.medium.com/how-to-use-svg-in-react-native-e581eca59534

ps: I would like to thank **Jayant kumar yadav** for posting that blog

Answer (score 3):

If you're using React Native with TypeScript, here is the step-by-step solution:

**1. Install `react-native-svg`**

```
npm install react-native-svg
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-svg
```

**2. Link native code**

```
cd ios && pod install
```

**3. Install `react-native-svg-transformer`**

```
npm install --save-dev react-native-svg-transformer
```

or

```
yarn add --dev react-native-svg-transformer
```

**4. Configure the react native packager**

*For React Native v0.59 or newer*:

Merge the contents from your project's `metro.config.js` file with this config (create the file if it does not exist already).

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

This is how my merged `metro.config.js` looks like:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config')

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig()
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  }
})()
```

**5. TypeScript configuration:**

If you are using TypeScript, you need to add this to your `declarations.d.ts` file (create one if you don't have one already):

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from 'react';
  import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";
  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}
```

**6. Usage**

```
...
import LogSvg from '../assets/images/Logo.svg'

export function LandingScreen(): JSX.Element {
  ...
  return (
    <View style={style.mainContainer}>
      <LogSvg style={style.logoContainer} />
    </View>
  )
}

...
```

Comment: this is a really good working solution as well

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383446/13278127

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react'
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

export default function Splash() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* provided the svg file is stored locally */}
      <SvgUri
        width="400"
        height="200"
        source={require('./logo.svg')}
      />
      {/* if the svg is online */}
      <SvgUri
        width="200"
        height="200"
        source={{ uri: 'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg' }}
      />

      <Text style={styles.logoText}>
        Text
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  logoText: {
    fontSize: 50
  }
});
```

Comment: use ```npm install react-native-svg-uri --save``` to install the needed package

Answer (score 1):

I try to use `SvgCssUri` and it works

```
import { SvgCssUri } from 'react-native-svg';
...
...
...
<SvgCssUri 
style={{height: 100, width: 100}} 
uri={"http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg"} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Svg does not work for android release versions so do not consider for android. It will work for android in debug mode only. But it works fine for ios.

Use https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri

Install

```
npm install react-native-svg-uri --save
react-native link react-native-svg # not react-native-svg-uri
```

Usage

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';


<SvgUri source={require('./path_to_image/image.svg')} />
```

Comment: @AravindVemula you are right. It does not work for android release versions. I also couldn't find a solution. Probably there is no solution till now. I abandoned using svg and turned back to the traditional way of react native images

Answer (score 0):

I use these two plugins,

1. [react-native-svg] https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)
2. [
   react-native-svg-transformer] https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer)

First off all,
You need to install that plugin. After that you need to change your metro.config.js, with this code.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

For more details, you can visit this link

- https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-import-svgs-on-react-native-dc76b56403ba
- https://medium.com/@majirosstefan/the-svgs-inside-react-native-0-61-5-and-storybook-566bcd43ba94

Answer (score 0):

1. First install `react-native-svg` to your project.
2. Open https://react-svgr.com/ and go to the playground and select React native
3. Copy paste your SVG code and used the output code.

Ex:- This is the sample SVG that I have got.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
    <defs>
        <path id="a" d="M16.191 1.027L9.023 8.196l7.168 7.168-.83.83-7.169-7.167-7.168 7.168-.831-.831L7.36 8.196.19 1.027l.832-.83L8.19 7.366 15.359.197z"/>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </mask>
        <use fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#a"/>
        <g fill="#3D3D3D" mask="url(#b)">
            <path d="M0 0h16v16H0z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Output:-

```
import * as React from "react"
import Svg, { Defs, Path, G, Mask, Use } from "react-native-svg"

function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width={17}
      height={17}
      viewBox="0 0 17 17"
      {...props}
    >
      <Defs>
        <Path
          id="prefix__a"
          d="M16.191 1.027L9.023 8.196l7.168 7.168-.83.83-7.169-7.167-7.168 7.168-.831-.831L7.36 8.196.19 1.027l.832-.83L8.19 7.366 15.359.197z"
        />
      </Defs>
      <G fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <Mask id="prefix__b" fill="#fff">
          <Use xlinkHref="#prefix__a" />
        </Mask>
        <Use fill="#FFF" fillRule="nonzero" xlinkHref="#prefix__a" />
        <G fill="#3D3D3D" mask="url(#prefix__b)">
          <Path d="M0 0h16v16H0z" />
        </G>
      </G>
    </Svg>
  )
}

export default SvgComponent
```

** But when I use the above code in my project and it does not render properly. So I done it as below and somehow it works for me.

```
import * as React from "react"
import Svg, { Path, G } from "react-native-svg"

function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Svg
      width={17}
      height={17}
      {...props}
    >
        <G>
            <Path
                id="prefix__a"
                d="M16.191 1.027L9.023 8.196l7.168 7.168-.83.83-7.169-7.167-7.168 7.168-.831-.831L7.36 8.196.19 1.027l.832-.83L8.19 7.366 15.359.197z"
            />
        </G>
    </Svg>
  )
}

export default SvgComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a new library to be able to use native vector assets based on `.svg` files called [react-native-vector-image](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-image). It doesn't need any custom babel transforms and you can use it like you would for other bitmap based assets, but there is an extra step in transforming the svg to the native equivalents (you only need to run it when you add new assets though).

Using your example the code would look something like this

```
import VectorImage from 'react-native-vector-image';

<View>
  <VectorImage source={require('./svg/1f604.svg')} />
</View>
```

Comment: Can we send some extra props to the VectorImage component? Something like dynamic color for the element in the svg file?

Comment: You can set a `tintColor` prop.

Comment: But I guess `tintColor` will add color to the whole svg file.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a static image not a react component. You can provide a dark mode or high contrast version, but you are limited to what a static image file can do, so no logic. Maybe you can explain what you want to acheive?

Comment: I am trying to create an avatar selection screen, In which I can change the color of the hair and facial color. The designer gave me svg file.

Comment: That sounds like a job for `react-native-svg`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that worked for me on both platforms is https://github.com/seekshiva/react-native-remote-svg.

I additionally did a conditional render with https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg to have the best result on both platforms, because there's an know issue with Android as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54182426/4934132.

Just in case I have `ErrorBoundry` to cover the exceptions.

It looks like this:

```
<ErrorBoundary
  FallbackComponent={error => ErrorFallback(error)}
  onReset={() => {
    // reset the state of your app so the error doesn't happen again
  }}
  onError={myErrorHandler}
>
  {Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
    <SvgCssUri width="100%" height="100%" uri={url} />
    :
    <Image
      source={{ uri: url }}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: '100%' }}
    />
  }
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Converting .svg image to JSX with https://svg2jsx.herokuapp.com/

- Then save the JSX code in assest/SVGFile.js
- Then import it, for example `import open from "../../../../assets/SVGFile";`
- Lastly add `<SvgXml xml={open} scaleX={2} scaleY={2} width={20} height={20} />`

Make sure to install, yarn add react-native-svg

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is stuck on this bug in 2022, here's the solution that worked for me:

1. **Install react-native-svg-transformer**:
   `yarn add react-native-svg-transformer --dev`
   *or using npm*
   `npm install react-native-svg-transformer --save-dev`
2. **Install react-native-svg**:
   `yarn add react-native-svg`
   *or using npm*
   `npm install react-native-svg --save`
3. **Update your metro.config.js file to looks like this:**

```js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = (() => { 
    const {  
        resolver: { 
            sourceExts, 
            assetExts 
        }  
    } = getDefaultConfig(__dirname); 

    return {
        transformer: {      
            babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")    
        },    
        resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]    
        }};
})();
```

4. **Import and display the `svg` image in your code like below:**

```js
import {View} from 'react-native';
import SvgImage from './path/to/svg/file.svg';

function MyComponent(){
    return (
        <View>
          <SvgImage />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use **react-native-svg** [see](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) its supports both android and Ios.

this is the basic example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

export default () => (
  <SvgUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg"
  />
);
```

if you want to use both normal image and svg images in one component, You can make a custom function that checks if the url has svg and return **Image** component or **SvgUri**

```
        const ImageComponent = (Props) => {
            const {Istyle, url, mode} = props;
            const isSvg = url?.includes('.svg') ?? false;
        
            if (isSvg) {
              return <SvgCssUri style={Istyle} uri={defaultAvatar} />;
            }
            if (!isSvg) {
              return <Image style={Istyle} source={{uri: url}} resizeMode={mode} />;
            }
          };

//let testURl = "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/john.svg"
```

Answer (score -11):

one option is to just convert to PNGs and use those. They work more reliably, generally

Comment: It is an open-source project - I'm sure they'd be happy with your pull request if you have a better solution than mentioned above... :)