# How to add programmatically add an SVG element to a component using react-native-svg module?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I'm searching without success information everywhere on the web on how to create an SVG Rect element in React-Native using the react-native-svg feature.
What I reached so far is to define some SVG elements in a component and to pass props to the existing SVG Elements like Rect , Circle and so on.
But how can I programmatically create a random number of SVG elements and to attach them to the component ? Sadly, it is not specified in the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by create an SVG Rect component and Random Number of SVG elements. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Exactly what i said..Create for example a Rect element and attach it to the Canvas..in some sorts of For cycles or similiar.

Comment: Will this repo be useful for you https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything on the react-native-svg also.

But this post could be helpfull: [How to show SVG file on React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830568/how-to-show-svg-file-on-react-native).

You have to convert the .svg to JSX like is answered there by Ihor Burlachenko, notice that react-native is deferent from react, in react-native you need to use the react-native-svg module to create the svg JSX component