# Acessing files from other subfolders React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an svg file inside assets / shape_dividers that I want to access. But the problem is that I want to access from Welcome.js . I was searching in some other posts and they say to install babel-plugin-module-resolver but I still have problems.

.babelrc File

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [ "module-resolver", { "root": ["./"] } ] 
  ]
}
```

Welcome.js

```js
import Wave from 'assets/shape_dividers/wave';
```

Directory:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show SVG file on React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830568/how-to-show-svg-file-on-react-native)

Comment: @Kai I am answering about acessing an file of assets in a script on views

Comment: I understand, but the way you are trying to import that SVG is not going to work

Comment: @Kai https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-use-svg-in-react-native-e581eca59534

Comment: @Kai I will take a look at this post, but how can I acess the assets folder?

Comment: It looks like your filepath needs to be `'../assets/shape_dividers/wave.svg'`

Comment: @Kai Error 500 https://pastebin.com/K94JpEJj

Comment: I suspect your metro.config.js is not set up correctly, you'll want to verify that it matches the example

Comment: I copy and paste the example again to be exactly the same thing, but the error continue except when I remove import

Comment: @Kai problem solved. I was using shape not shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

1- I uses .. to back one folder

2. I was using shape rather than **shapes**

Final Code:

```
  import Wave from '../assets/shapes_dividers/wave.svg';
```