# React Native how to render svg from url

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm trying to render svg file path from @dicebear/avatars

```
  let svg = createAvatar(style, {
    seed: 'random',
    // ... and other options
  });
```

svg variable has this value = [image]

But when i try to render in react-native is not showing even if i use a library called react-native-render-html
I'm trying to render using the library like this

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <HTML source={{ html: svg }} />

  <StatusBar style="white" />
</View>
```

When i do this this is what i get[[image: what i see when i try to render1]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830568/how-to-show-svg-file-on-react-native) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, i dont have .svg file i only have the html svg code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg).
Steps:

1. Install the library using `npm install react-native-svg`
2. Rebuild the app after clearing the cache.
3. Now use the XML like

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAvatar} from '@dicebear/avatars';
import * as style from '@dicebear/avatars-identicon-sprites';
import {SvgCss} from 'react-native-svg';

const xml = createAvatar(style, {
  seed: 'custom-seed',
});

export default function App() {
  return <SvgCss xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />;
}
```

Comment: @Dawker I think you messed up with import or export for any component. Please make sure you're doing it correctly, this error has nothing to do with this library.